# Wavelets and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, wavelet

I am trying to learn features from a signal using Wavelet transform and then apply ML techniques on it to classify a signal. The problem I am facing is that, at each of level of decomposition, my signal has a vector, and I have more than 10,000 signals.

Or let me rephrase: Suppose I want to classify if a house will sell or not. Each house has a lot of features that let me decide. In my feature matrix, each row represents a single house. And in each row, each column represents a random variable pertaining to size, lawn, floorplan etc..

But in the case of Wavelets, I have a signal which I have decomposed. Every level of decomposition has a vector associated with it. And there are many signals. Now in my feature matrix, every row represents a single signal. And each rows' each column is a random variable which is supposed to be a scalar, but in this case, it is a vector. Does anyone know how to tackle this problem? I can't do averaging or mean or suppose it belongs to any distribution.

Comment: (i) What "signal" are you using the wavelet to represent? (i)What are you trying to achieve with the wavelets?

Comment: Can't you simply flatten the vector out? I mean, from what you describe it feels that for each signal, you have a 2D matrix, in which case, you can simply write the matrix out in row-major order or column major order and create a single vector out of your signals.

Comment: Nick, I have current samples that I am trying to decompose on various levels since it is not a stationary signal. At each level of decomposition, I will have some information about the current samples. These decomposition vectors will then be used as features. But the problem is that each decomposition is a vector, instead of a scalar. How do I model this kind of distribution such that it can represented by a single variable?

Tenali, I had that in mind, but it doesn't sound intuitive or rather makes sense to me. What do I actually imply by that transformation?

Comment: There is no meaning to that transformation, we are just using a 1D representation for a 2D space. On the other hand, you can give very specific meaning to this representation by controlling the weights in your classifier. For example, you can enforce that all weights corresponding to a particular column should be equal OR enforce a block/mixed norm regularizer like for example, you can enforce a 2-norm regularizer over the weights corresponding to a single column vector and 1-norm regularizer overall.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @TenaliRaman. You should simply flatten your the 2D matrix with shape(m x n) of wavelet coefficients at different level to a 1D vector with shape(1, m x n).